# HTML DIV's stack one below the other when resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css

Have not worked much on UI front. I have a main div , and 2 nested div's. The 2 div's appear one besides the other, but when I resize the window the div's stack one below the other. My requirement is, Though I resize the window the divs should be place one besides the other and browser window should have a scroll bar horizontally to scroll right if i want to see the contents.

I did try various approaches but could not succeed.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

#mainContainer {
  overflow: hidden
}

#firstBox {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 45%;
  height: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

#secondBox {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 45%;
  height: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="firstBox" class="gridContainer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam eros posuere quam, non ipsum ornare vehicula. In integer, ac tempus aenean lorem nec amet ac, non blandit class, eget odio eu, mollis mauris massa. In augue erat convallis, morbi lectus lobortis tempor in lorem. Dis
    et morbi consectetuer non, tempor pretium. Leo dolor erat orci, lobortis adipisicing scelerisque integer diam lorem, tempus non, dolor libero vivamus velit. Viverra ipsum quam id in arcu, ligula tortor laoreet fermentum sit ipsum. Erat dapibus nulla
    justo vitae, feugiat nullam felis sollicitudin, dolor wisi mauris, tristique tempus nunc tristique. Velit non, duis auctor a. Ipsum pede maecenas vestibulum id ornare, ac facilisi wisi maecenas sem ultrices, non pede cupiditate mollis lorem condimentum,
    suscipit integer etiam mauris amet. Magna rutrum cras, tincidunt lacus ut, lectus donec
  </div>

  <div id="secondBox" class="gridContainer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam eros posuere quam, non ipsum ornare vehicula. In integer, ac tempus aenean lorem nec amet ac, non blandit class, eget odio eu, mollis mauris massa. In augue erat convallis, morbi lectus lobortis tempor in lorem. Dis
    et morbi consectetuer non, tempor pretium. Leo dolor erat orci, lobortis adipisicing scelerisque integer diam lorem, tempus non, dolor libero vivamus velit. Viverra ipsum quam id in arcu, ligula tortor laoreet fermentum sit ipsum. Erat dapibus nulla
    justo vitae, feugiat nullam felis sollicitudin, dolor wisi mauris, tristique tempus nunc tristique. Velit non, duis auctor a. Ipsum pede maecenas vestibulum id ornare, ac facilisi wisi maecenas sem ultrices, non pede cupiditate mollis lorem condimentum,
    suscipit integer etiam mauris amet. Magna rutrum cras, tincidunt lacus ut, lectus donec,
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's wrong in above code..! its work properly

Comment: after adding "position: fixed" in #secondBox it is working fine (div's placed one besides the other was my first requirement) ,  but when I re size the browser window horizontally, instead of div text shrinking to adjust the window, i want a scrollbar in the browser window horizontally so that i can scroll to see the 2nd div.

Comment: use min-width to div it will stay not shrink. Then set parent overflow-x:auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this add width to container & child elements.

```css
#mainContainer
{
    width:1490px;
    height:auto; 
    overflow-x: auto;
}   
#firstBox {
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;   
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;  
    float: left;
    
}

#secondBox {
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    left:750px;
    float: left;
   
}
```

```html
    <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="firstBox" class="gridContainer">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam eros posuere quam, non ipsum
            ornare vehicula. In integer, ac tempus aenean lorem nec amet ac, non
            blandit class, eget odio eu, mollis mauris massa. In augue erat
            convallis, morbi lectus lobortis tempor in lorem. Dis et morbi
            consectetuer non, tempor pretium. Leo dolor erat orci, lobortis
            adipisicing scelerisque integer diam lorem, tempus non, dolor libero
            vivamus velit. Viverra ipsum quam id in arcu, ligula tortor laoreet
            fermentum sit ipsum. Erat dapibus nulla justo vitae, feugiat nullam
            felis sollicitudin, dolor wisi mauris, tristique tempus nunc
            tristique. Velit non, duis auctor a. Ipsum pede maecenas vestibulum
            id ornare, ac facilisi wisi maecenas sem ultrices, non pede
            cupiditate mollis lorem condimentum, suscipit integer etiam mauris
            amet. Magna rutrum cras, tincidunt lacus ut, lectus donec
    </div>

    <div id="secondBox" class="gridContainer">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam eros posuere quam, non ipsum
            ornare vehicula. In integer, ac tempus aenean lorem nec amet ac, non
            blandit class, eget odio eu, mollis mauris massa. In augue erat
            convallis, morbi lectus lobortis tempor in lorem. Dis et morbi
            consectetuer non, tempor pretium. Leo dolor erat orci, lobortis
            adipisicing scelerisque integer diam lorem, tempus non, dolor libero
            vivamus velit. Viverra ipsum quam id in arcu, ligula tortor laoreet
            fermentum sit ipsum. Erat dapibus nulla justo vitae, feugiat nullam
            felis sollicitudin, dolor wisi mauris, tristique tempus nunc
            tristique. Velit non, duis auctor a. Ipsum pede maecenas vestibulum
            id ornare, ac facilisi wisi maecenas sem ultrices, non pede
            cupiditate mollis lorem condimentum, suscipit integer etiam mauris
            amet. Magna rutrum cras, tincidunt lacus ut, lectus donec,
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code is already working fine and it isn't stacking one below the other I guess, can you tell me when did it stack one below the other.

Comment: after adding "position: fixed" in #secondBox it is working fine (div's placed one besides the other was my first requirement) , but when I re size the browser window horizontally, instead of div text shrinking to adjust the window, i want a scrollbar in the browser window horizontally so that i can scroll to see the 2nd div.

Comment: Yes, it's made like that. You have given margin and padding as 10px(which makes it 20px+20px=40px on left(20) and right(20)) So, when your div size comes below 360 size it starts going to next row as it can't get 10px padding and 10px margin in the first row because it's width is also fixed to 45%.I think when screen size is somewhere around 820, 2nd div goes to next row. For your understanding remove or reduce padding and marigin and check. So to get the assigned padding and margin it floats to next row. Hope you understood it, feel free to ask further and accept the answer is you are clear